# Factors or dummy variables for a categorical binary response variable? Which approach is better for Machine Learning/Logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data

I am new to R and I  am  creating a glm for  a dataset  trying to see the covariates that affect if someone is hyper or not hyper(my  target categorical  binary variable)[hyperness variable].
I am wondering whether it makes a difference to create a  dummy variable that is coded as 0 and 1 or use the as.factor function  that is coded as 1,2 ?
All the other variables are continuous.

Thank you

Comment: If the model is a sum, 0 and 1. If a power function, i.e., a product, 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

The `glm` function is pretty smart. If it sees a factor with two levels, it will dummy code it for you.